# Ajax cross-domain request to REST api

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest, cross-domain, http-status-code-404

I have REST api on backend. I need to make ajax request to POST some data and I write:

```
$(function() { 
    $('#createPin').click(function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault();

var urlAjax = "http://www.agroagro.com/test/v1/register";

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: urlAjax,
contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
data: {
                    name: "Mile3",
                    email: "new1@new.com",
                    password: "face1book"
                },
  crossDomain:true, 
  success: function(data) { console.log(data); },
error: function(data) {console.log(data); },
dataType: 'json',
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        },
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        }
});


}); 
});
```

but on click I get:

```
         OPTIONS http://www.agroagro.com/test/v1/register jquery-latest.min.js:4 sendjquery-latest.min.js:4 m.extend.ajaxtest.html:114 (anonymous function)jquery-latest.min.js:3 m.event.dispatchjquery-latest.min.js:3 r.handle

    XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.agroagro.com/test/v1/register. Invalid HTTP status code 404

    Object {readyState: 0, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, 

setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}
```

But when I try to run http://www.agroagro.com/test/v1/register on `Chrome Advanced Rest Client extension` then all works fine... How and why? What is wrong with my ajax request?

**See IMAGE**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnZCX.png - **as you can see all works great with that extension cross domain.**

Comment: try faking the request by sending origin and user-agent headers

Comment: please show example here in an naswer

Comment: record the ajax request/response (using network tab in developer tools) and share it here.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/x5zYTQj.png

Comment: its so strange how Chrome Rest client extension works great and my ajax request not SEE: http://i.imgur.com/Ms0oBK9.png

Comment: try adding `xhrFields: {withCredentials: true }` to your ajax request

Comment: Now I get:  XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.agroagro.com/test/v1/register. A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true. Origin 'http://agroagro.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: @LaraBeginer — So set the specific origin instead of using a wildcard.

Comment: How please show example

Comment: I write answer for working example but why XHR this work and ajax dont?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

send the below headers from your server

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin : THE SITE FROM WHICH YOU WILL MAKE THE AJAX REQUEST
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials : true
```

then in jquery add the below code

```
xhrFields: {withCredentials: true }
```

Comment: yes but I dont know which domain will be becouse I create mobile phonegap app and that app dont have url

Comment: I add header: header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials : true");
but again is the same

Comment: if the request is send from a mobile app then you dont need anything like `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, but if you send the request from some website based IDE then you need to worry about all thest things. i think you are testing the app from a web based IDE am i right?

Comment: i testing app from a browser ... please go at: http://agroagro.com/test.html and click on button then see console

Comment: thats the point. run it from mobile not from a typical web browser

Comment: but phonegap works like native app but in behind phonegap is just mobil browser

Comment: yes that is correct. when you run the ajax from `agroagro.com/test.html` (in web browser) its considered as the reques is sent from agroagro.com but if you run it in mobile it will act just like your Rest Client (chrome extension)

Comment: NO. export it as an apk then install it and run it

Comment: Are you sure about that?

Comment: I have got one issue for my app and it was fixed like this

Comment: You think that this will work witout issue if the ajax request come from native app?

Comment: YES it will. (try that and please share the feedback so that others can get benefit)

Comment: I try with: PhoneGap emulator but dont work: http://www.agroagro.com/test.html?enableripple=cordova

Comment: I write answer for working example but why this work and ajax dont?

Answer (score 2):

It is your backend API that needs to return the proper [CORS](http://www.enable-cors.org) header. In the easiest variant, just have the server reply to the preflight request (HTTP `OPTIONS` verb) with this header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

When you already have this response header set up, please note that your question shows a `404` code (Not Found). When I browse to http://www.agroagro.com/test/v1/register, I am seeing a `404`, too. This may only be the case for `GET` requests, though.

By setting the `crossDomain` property to `true`, you are telling jQuery to send a JSONP request. A JSONP request works by embedding a `<script>` tag into the body, which triggers a `GET` request.

When the server is equipped with the proper CORS headers, you should disable `crossDomain`. Since, according to the jQuery documentation, `crossDomain` defaults to `true` if the target domain differs from the domain of the currently open web page, use this snippet:

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        crossDomain: false,
        // ...
    });

---

For cross-domain requests, the browser sends a preflight request like this first:

```
OPTIONS /test/v1/register HTTP/1.1
Host: www.agroagro.com
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://agroagro.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.62 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: access-control-allow-origin, accept, x-requested-with, content-type
Accept: */*
Referer: http://agroagro.com/test.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
```

To find out if the browser may send the POST request, the server response is checked for an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.  However, when receiving the above request, the API server replies like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 28 Nov 2014 10:37:18 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d57edcdbd0a20a0d11df4dda7c3753d611417171038; expires=Sat, 28-Nov-15 10:37:18 GMT; path=/; domain=.agroagro.com; HttpOnly
Allow: POST,OPTIONS,GET,HEAD
Set-Cookie: PH_HPXY_CHECK=s1; path=/
Cache-control: private
Server: cloudflare-nginx
CF-RAY: 1905edebcdb50f69-FRA
```

As you can see, there is no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header returned for the `OPTIONS` request.

Solution: Have the API endpoint return the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header not only for the `POST` request, but rather for the preflight `OPTIONS` request.

Comment: but I put that header into backend... also how chrome extension can work well and send good data?

Comment: ok, yes, but this is backedn stuff that developer to work like that ... but try with Chrome rest extension then works fine, also works fine with same hosting request

Comment: @LaraBeginer — The chrome extension is software installed in the user's browser and given permission to access arbitary other websites. Your JavaScript is not.

Comment: Again I get:  XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.agroagro.com/test/v1/register. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://agroagro.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: @Quentin but Chrome extension also send cross-domain request

Comment: @LaraBeginer — Because it is a Chrome extension that the user explicitly installed and not JS on a webpage the user happened to visit.

Comment: I testing app from a browser , please go at http://agroagro.com/test.html click on button then go to console log

Comment: @LaraBeginer As outlined in the last part of my answer, your code has `crossDomain:true`. Please set this to `false` to disable `JSONP` in favor of normal `CORS` requests.

Comment: @LaraBeginer See the second part of my edited answer, below the horizontal line.

Comment: If I make .apk phonegap native app (in which behind is browser) can I use rest as Chrome extension does?

Comment: “PhoneGap you can just XHR directly to remote servers and it should ‘just work’. Cross-domain policy does not apply to PhoneGap.” – As answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21299355/486298

Comment: SO with PhoneGap this will work just fine witout any changes?

Comment: Exactly. Just leave `crossDomain` to `false`.

Comment: I try with PhoneGap emulator: http://www.agroagro.com/test.html?enableripple=cordova but dont work

Comment: I write answer for working example but why this work and ajax dont?