# Cordova external app + local video

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, html5-video, phonegap-build

We have an iOS app built with PhoneGap / Cordova 4.3.0. This app directly loads an external website by using `<content src="http://example.com/foo" />` in the `config.xml` file. All the functionality is contained within this website, so we are not actually using any local HTML or JS files.

As part of the app functionality, we must play some videos. Because the app is designed to work offline as well, we want to cache these videos locally. Therefore we are downloading them to the device using the FileTransfer plugin, along with other resources such as images or PDFs. After downloading the files we are getting URLs with the `file://` protocol. We also have the option of using the `cdvfile://` protocol. When we use `cdvfile://` URLs to show images, the images show up correctly. However, videos do not play at all.

To play videos we are using standard HTML5 video tags:

```
<video width="auto" height="100%" controls="controls" autoplay="true">
    <source src="..." type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

The videos themselves are working, and they will play correctly from an external source (as in, they will play if we are accessing them from the server instead of the local filesystem). I realize that the problem has something to do with web-related concepts such as the same-origin policy and with the restriction to access the local filesystem. However, at the same time I must wonder why it is that images are working fine under these same constraints.

What I have tried so far:

1. Using `file://` and `cdvfile://` URLs as the `src` of the video. This does not produce any sort of visual effect. The screen is simply black.
2. Using an `iframe` with the `src` set to the video URL. When using `file://`, the screen is still black. However, when using `cdvfile://`, the iOS video player interface appears, with a play button and a full-screen button, but the video does not play and there is no timeline either.
3. Adding a local file to cordova called `video.html` which takes a URL as parameter and renders a `video` tag with that URL as `src`. The plan was to include this file as an `iframe`, but apparently I can't make an `iframe` to a local file. I have tried various URLs that might point to that particular `video.html` file (though in truth I'm not sure this is possible). Among the ones I tried were: `cordova.file.applicationDirectory + 'www/video.html'`, `http://localhost/www/video.html`, `cdvfile://localhost/www/video.html`.
4. I looked for some cordova plugin that will play videos, but I have been unsuccessful in finding one for iOS. Most plugins seem to be targeted towards Android.

Now, it's possible that I'm going about this in a wrong way. As I see it, the "standard use case" for cordova is that you store your HTML/JS/CSS files locally. External content like the one I'm using is probably a bit unusual. I will explain the requirements for this app that have brought me to use this functionality.

- The app is supposed to be built for multiple platforms (though we're starting with iOS). Therefore we are using PhoneGap.
- It is supposed to be accessible both online and offline, though all the content comes from the server (no content is produced locally). This is why we are downloading content and saving it locally.
- It is also supposed to auto-update any part of itself on the fly, without requiring an update from the App Store. This is why we are using an external page - because it has a `cache.manifest` that allows us to control updates to the web app code, while at the same time allowing it to be cached locally. This is probably the most important thing to consider, because if we wanted to keep some files locally within Cordova, we would have to re-implement this cache functionality within Javascript (using as thin a layer as possible).

In any case, my main concern is how to get these videos working. I am willing to try the hackiest workarounds! If it's really not possible with the current development decisions, then maybe you could give me some hints as to how I should structure the app in order to make it work and still fulfill my requirements.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I recommend using  a remote debugger and looking at what's going on in the network. Maybe mime file types are not ok.

Comment: Are you using `.toURL()` anywhere? If so, try replacing with `.toNativeURL()`

Comment: I have tried the suggestions and my findings are:
@SergeySnegirev I have debugged the incoming files. The mime types are ok. The files are successfully downloaded to the device. However, I cannot debug requests made through the `file://` or `cdvfile://` protocols, since they don't actually go through the network.

@FlyingLemon I have tried `.toURL()`, `.toNativeURL()` and `.toInternalURL()`. The first two give me a `file://` URL while the last gives me a `cdvfile://` URL. `cdvfile://` URLs work for images, but not for videos.

Comment: @Grampa I found other people have a similar problem, try using the _dev branch_ of the **file plugin**, the **file transfer plugin** and the **media plugin**.

Comment: @FlyingLemon Thank you for the advice. I have just tried using the dev branch of the file and file transfer plugins (I'm not using the media plugin at all). However, the build fails if I use this branch, because of a dependency on the CDVFilesystemURL interface, which cannot be found. I have studied the plugin code a bit and indeed, this interface is only present in the release version of the file plugin. The dev branches were last updated 11 months ago, so maybe the code is too outdated to be used.

Comment: Hi @Grampa, I'm not sure how you are debugging the app, but try the following: Connect your iOS device to your computer (or use the simulator), open Safari, choose the app from your device in "develop" menu, verify that the resources (including file://xxx) are located where you expect, also you can modify the code inside safari to change url and test

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar project about a year ago. But i don't remember running into this issue because we were bundling our html/js/css assets with the app.

The issue is that your are trying to load file:/// protocol url from an html file served from http:/// protocol, which is not something that the native UIWebView is comfortable with.

You can bypass this by using a custom URL scheme like video://, but you need to write some native code which intercepts this requests and pipes the actual video back to URL loading system.

The end result:

[image: The end result]

Here is how i did it using Cordova 4.3.0 & a bit of ObjectiveC

1. Create a new Objective C class named VideoURLProtocol which extends NSURLProtocol:

VideoURLProtocol.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface VideoURLProtocol : NSURLProtocol <NSURLConnectionDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSURLConnection *connection;

@end
```

VideoURLProtocol.m:

```
#import "VideoURLProtocol.h"

@implementation VideoURLProtocol

@synthesize connection;

+ (BOOL)canInitWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request {
    return [[[request URL] absoluteString] rangeOfString:@"video://"].location != NSNotFound;
}

+ (NSURLRequest *)canonicalRequestForRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request {
    return request;
}

+ (BOOL)requestIsCacheEquivalent:(NSURLRequest *)a toRequest:(NSURLRequest *)b {
    return [super requestIsCacheEquivalent:a toRequest:b];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    [self.client URLProtocol:self didReceiveResponse:response cacheStoragePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [self.client URLProtocol:self didLoadData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    [self.client URLProtocolDidFinishLoading:self];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [self.client URLProtocol:self didFailWithError:error];
}

- (void)startLoading {
    NSString *currentURL = [[self.request URL] absoluteString];
    NSString *newURL = [currentURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"video://" withString:@"file:///"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:newURL]];
    self.connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}

- (void)stopLoading {
    [self.connection cancel];
    self.connection = nil;
}

@end
```

2. Add the following line to the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method of AppDelegate.m

   ```
   .
   .
   // These lines should already be there
   self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

   // This line
   [NSURLProtocol registerClass:[VideoURLProtocol class]];
   .
   .
   ```
3. And here's the javascript code that utilises this new URL scheme

   ```
   document.addEventListener('deviceready', function(){    
       window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem){        
           var caches = fileSystem.root.nativeURL.replace("Documents", "Library/Caches"), 
               videoPath = caches + "video.mp4";
           new FileTransfer().download("http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4", videoPath, function(entry){            
               document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0].src = caches.replace("file:///", "video://") + "video.mp4"
           }, function(error){
               alert("unable to download file: " + error);
           });
       });
   }, false);
   ```

Some additional points worth mentioning:

Notice in my javascript code i am downloading the file to "/Library/Caches" instead of the "/Documents" directory (the default location) this is because the "/Documents" directory gets backed up to iCloud & Apple rejects apps that try to backup more than ~100 MB. This is something I found the hard way after getting my App rejected.
You can see the space taken by your app under: Settings > iCloud > Storage > Manage Storage > {{Your iphone name}} > Show All Apps

You can autoplay videos by add the following line to your config.xml

```
<preference name="MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
```

You can also play videos inline by adding the following line to your config.xml in addition to this you also need to add webkit-playsinline="true" attribute to your video:

```
<preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true" />

<video controls="controls" autoplay="true" webkit-playsinline="true" preload="auto">
</video>
```

Here's a really interesting tutorial by Ray that explains NSURLProtocol in great detail: http://www.raywenderlich.com/59982/nsurlprotocol-tutorial

Comment: This turned out to be the working solution! Following these instructions exactly and rewriting the `file:///` URLs obtained from `toURL()` into `video://` links solved the problem nicely. For anybody attempting to use this solution for their own project, be especially mindful of the search and replace: `file:///` with 3 slashes is replaced with `video://` with 2 slashes.

Comment: Some time after trying out this solution, I'd like to point out an issue (not with the poster's explanation, but with iOS itself). If you use the above method to insert a `<video>` tag with the source set to the indicated URL, then the app will load the entire video into memory at once, without buffering. In our case, we first loaded a 10MB video, which was fine. Then we loaded a 300MB video and the app instantly crashed. The solution we ended up using was a free third-party video player, which streams rather than loads videos.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience using the `file://` protocol has been problematic on iOS because the protocol starts at the root of the device filesystem.

I don't believe that any Cross-Origin problems are being faced here because Cordova doesn't implement Cross-Origin requests, but rather treats all requests as coming from the origin to which they are requesting. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21299355/2619800).

My theoretical solution is using a **relative** URL instead of trying to use any protocol at all. However, the way you implement this might depend on when the file is successfully downloaded.

```
<video width="auto" height="100%" controls="controls" autoplay="true">
    <source src="/localhost/www/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Where `cdvfile://localhost/www/` was the path you set for the `target` argument when you called `fileTransfer.download()` [referenced here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer#download).

It may be necessary to either create the video element or set the video src in javascript once the `successCallback` has fired. Again you would set the src as a relative URL.

**Please note videos will not autoplay on mobile**

[From the Safari Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH5-SW4)

> In Safari on iOS (for all devices, including iPad), where the user may be on a cellular network and be charged per data unit, preload and autoplay are disabled.