# Cross origin request fails even though both CSP and <access origin=''> are set

Tags: cordova

Im using `Cordova 5.0.0` and `cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.0.0` and im deploying to `Android 5.1` on a Nexus 5 phone.

This is what my `config.xml` looks like (note that im using a remote source in the content tag (as in not local to the phone), dont know if thats relevant or not):

```
<access origin="*" />
<access origin="http://remotedomain.com" />
<content src="http://localdomain.com/app.html" />
```

EDIT: content src is relevant! tried running my app normally from a local source by setting `<content src="app.html">` and everything works! Hmm. So is it impossible to use a remote src? I'd very much like to during development as it allows for a much faster write run debug cycle.

This is what my CSP looks like:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' remotedomain.com www.remotedomain.com * 'unsafe-inline'">
```

I know, vulnerable. Im just testing and just want to see it working as a first step.

My problem: XHRs to remotedomain.com are blocked by Chrome. This is what i see in the Chrome console which i connect to my phone using `chrome://inspect/#devices`

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://remotedomain.com/resource. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localdomain.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I have no control over remotedomain.com and there is no `JSONP` or `CORS`, its just a html page. How can i make XHRs to it from my app?

EDIT: content src is relevant! tried running my app normally from a local source by setting `<content src="app.html">` and everything works! Hmm. So is it impossible to use a remote src? I'd very much like to during development as it allows for a much faster write run debug cycle.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297169/cors-and-phonegap-apps)?

Comment: @KamilPajdzik i didnt, that was very useful! Thanks! I found out something from that link. It does make a difference what content src i use. If its a local url it all works fine! So its only when i use a remote content src that these cross origin requests are blocked!