# How to resolve CORS issue and JSONP issue in Ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic2, jsonp

I am new to `IONIC-2` and want to connect my mobile app to `Odoo - open source ecommerce`..
this connection involves some `JSONP` request.. I have done the same through `jQuery` previously.. its working properly in `phonegap` app.. but while I am doing the same thing with `IONIC-2` it gives me `CORS` and `JSONP` errors..

can someone help me in this..

my previous `jQuery` code is..

```
/******  index.js ******/

function json(url, params) {
   var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();

   uniq_id_counter += 1;
   var payload = {
      'jsonrpc': '2.0',
      'method': 'call',
      'params': params,
      'id': ("r" + uniq_id_counter)
   };

   rpc_jsonp(url, payload).then(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      if (data.error) {
          deferred.reject(data.error);
      }
      deferred.resolve(data.result, textStatus, jqXHR);
   });

   return deferred;
 }


function rpc_jsonp(url, payload) {

   // extracted from payload to set on the url
   var data = {
      session_id: window.localStorage.getItem("session_id"),
      id: payload.id
   };

   var ajax = {
     type: "POST",
     dataType: 'jsonp',
     jsonp: 'jsonp',
     cache: false,
     data: data,
     url: url
  };

  var payload_str = JSON.stringify(payload);
  var payload_url = jQuery.param({r: payload_str});
  if (payload_url.length < 2000) {
       //  throw new Error("Payload is too big.");
  }

  console.log(ajax);
  ajax.data.r = payload_str;
  console.log(ajax);
  return jQuery.ajax(ajax);

}
/******  index.js ******/
```

I am calling above `custom json` function `Login.html` file..

```
 /******  login.html ******/

 function login(){

   var base_url = 'MY_SERVER_URL';
   json(base_url+'web/session/authenticate', {
      'base_location': base_url,
      'db':'myDB',
      'login': 'admin',
      'password':'admin'
   }).done(function (data) {

   if(data.uid != false){
       alert(data);
   }
   else{
       alert('Invalid Username or Password.');
   }

   deferred.resolve();
 }).fail(function(data){
     alert('Invalid Username or Password.');
 });

  return deferred;
}
/******  login.html ******/
```

I tried followed code in `IONIC 2` while creating `service`

```
/****** OdooJsonService.ts ******/
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Jsonp, JSONP_PROVIDERS, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class OdooJsonService {
//data: any;
uniq_id_counter: number;
payload: any;
result_rpc: any;

constructor(private http: Http, private jsonp: Jsonp) {
  this.http = http;
  //this.data = null;
}

json(url, params) {

    this.uniq_id_counter = this.uniq_id_counter + 1;

    this.payload = JSON.stringify({
        'jsonrpc': '2.0',
        'method': 'call',
        'params': params,
        'id': ("r" + this.uniq_id_counter)
    });

    return this.rpc_jsonp(url, this.payload)
                    .map(res => res.json())
                    .catch(this.handleErrorOne);
}

rpc_jsonp(url, payload) {

    let data = JSON.stringify({
        //session_id: window.localStorage.getItem("session_id"),
        id: payload.id
    });

    let ajax = JSON.stringify({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'jsonp',
        cache: false,
        data: data,
        url: url
    });

    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'PUT, GET, POST',
                                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'});
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.post(url, ajax, options)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .catch(this.handleErrorTwo);
}

handleErrorOne(error) {
    console.error(error);
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
}

handleErrorTwo(error) {
    console.error(error);
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
}

 }       // End of OdooJsonService
 /****** OdooJsonService.ts ******/
```

and I am using above `service` in `Login.ts`

```
/****** login.ts ******/
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { App, NavController, MenuController, ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { TaskListPage } from '../task-list/task-list';

import { Http, Jsonp, JSONP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';
import { OdooJsonService } from '../../providers/odoo-json-service/odoo-json-service';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/login/login.html',
  providers: [OdooJsonService, JSONP_PROVIDERS]
})
export class LoginPage {
   public data: any;

   constructor(private nav: NavController, public odooJsonService: OdooJsonService) {
     this.odooMethod();
   }

   odooMethod() {
      this.odooJsonService
            .json('MY_SERVER_URL/web/session/authenticate', {'base_location': 'MY_SERVER_URL',
                    'db':'myDB', 'login': 'admin', 'password':'admin'})
            .subscribe(odooData => {
                this.data = odooData;
                console.log(JSON.stringify(this.data));
            });
     }

}
/****** login.ts ******/
```

error in console : 
(chrome)

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://MY_SERVER_URL/web/session/authenticate. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.
```

error in console : (firefox)

```
/web/session/authenticate: Function declared as capable of handling request of type 'json' but called with a request of type 'http'
```

I am not sure whether this is right approach.. Can anyone guide to do this in right order..

how can I achieve the same in `IONIC 2`??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## You can disable same origin policy in Chrome.

1. Create a separate chrome icon on your desktop.

[image: Dual Chrome]

2. Rename that icon to chrome (x-domain) so you know which is which.

[image: Chrome rename]

3. Right click on your new icon and click properties.

[image: Properties]

4. Change the target field to `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security --user-agent="Android" --user-data-dir="C:/temp-chrome-eng"`

[image: Target Field]

5. Click Ok.

The magic happens here:

```
--disable-web-security
```

When you open your browser it will look like this:

[image: Finished]

WARNING: ONLY USE FOR TESTING PURPOSES AS THIS BROWSER HAS SECURITY DISABLED.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're receiving is because your browser is blocking the cross-origin AJAX requests (the domain doesn't respond with the required headers). However if you execute the application on a mobile device, it should work, because the application will execute the request directly. You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297169/cors-and-phonegap-apps). Does it work if you launch the app on a mobile device?

Comment: Kuba is correct.  It should work when running your app on an android or ios device.  However for testing in the browser see my answer below.

Comment: On device there is no success or error log.

I'm not getting whether my code is wrong or something else that matters.

Comment: I've had problems with HTTPS using this, does the API site have correct certiticate accepted by Android? If it's possible, try using HTTP first. And put a breakpoint in the code so that you see that whether it actually executes.

Answer (score 0):

I am running on browser using `CORS extensions` and `plugins` on both `chrome` and `mozilla`. still there is no success.

I'm not getting whether my code is wrong or something else that matters.

**EDIT:** Follow below two comments to disable web security of chrome on MAC machine.

Comment: I resolved CORS issue on browser by disabling web security of chrome temporarily for development purpose only..
and changed my JSONService code..

Comment: disable web security of chrome on mac machine using following command. `open -n -a "Google Chrome" --args --user-data-dir=/tmp/temp_chrome_user_data_dir_for_cordova http://localhost:8100/index.html --disable-web-security`
This creates another instance of chrome with security is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

i had problem to use ionic and iis on same url ( localhost:8100 )
this chrome extension help me to solve cors issue: [enter link description here]

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/moesif-origin-cors-change/digfbfaphojjndkpccljibejjbppifbc

also for web api you can put this peace of code inside system.webServer tag in your web.config file

```
<system.webServer> 
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, 
DELETE, OPTIONS" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
...
</system.webServer>
```

make sure your header is correct:

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Content-Type');
```