# Ionic2/Angular2 CORS settings

Tags: cordova, angular, cors

Please help me to figure out with CORS on my Ionic2/Angular2 application.
I'm trying to get data with http 'GET' request.
When I'm running '$npm run build' at laptop, I get an expected response.
When I'm running '$ cordova run android', I always get 'Response with status: 0 for URL: null'.
Here is the code snippet:

```
this.http.get('https://httpbin.org/ip')
        .subscribe((data: any) => {
            this.result = data._body; // {"origin": "31.43.103.88"} on laptop
        }, error => {
            this.result = error; // 'Response with status: 0 for URL: null' on android
        });
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you manage to reach your ip from a browser ? Verify if port in not blocked by firewall also. If still not working, see this post : http://stackoverflow.com/a/36124935/2549619

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... It looks like I figured out by myself.
I did this:
1) ionic platform rm android
2) ionic platform add android
It's weird, but works like a charm.